# javascript:how to check for all requests to server from UI

Tags: javascript

I wanna check all request calls from browser...Is there any solution in Javascript

Comment: Check for what?  Why do you want to do this checking?  You need to provide more information...

Comment: all your requests ? or a specific type of requests? Do you want client side logging?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Net Panel in Firebug. http://getfirebug.com/